# An example of a non-constant function with the following properties

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-constant function with the following property: Given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a positive real number $r > 0$ and a set $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that

- Any interval $I$ with length $r >0$, is such that $D \cap I \ne \emptyset$
- $|f(x+t) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for any $t \in D$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$

---

I'm having a hard time picturing a function that is non-constant that satisfies both properties. If we take $D = \mathbb{Q}$ then the first property is easily satisfied, but I can't figure out what kind of function satisfies the second property. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: How about $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$

Comment: @Dylan: what is $D$ in your example?

Comment: @RobArthan $D = \mathbb{Q}$, as in the OP

Comment: You are right: this question is too easy. You should post your suggestion as an answer (with a little justification).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sin x$ and (no matter what $\epsilon$ is), let $r=2\pi$, $D=2\pi\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I have not seen the $2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ notation before, is it every element of $\mathbb{Z}$ multiplied by $2\pi$?

Comment: I don't think it is, since (I think) a set that is every element of $\mathbb{Z}$ multiplied by $2\pi$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $2\pi\Bbb{Z}$ here means the set of real numbers of the form $2\pi n$ where $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Apart from $0$, its elements are all irrational, so it is not the same as $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh wow, I read $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{C}$. My bad

Comment: I think the first property is not met? Since $2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I was wrong. Is not for all $r$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\Bbb{R}$ defined by $x \sim y$ iff $x - y \in \Bbb{Q}$ and let $P$ be the set of equivalence classes of $\sim$. Choose any non-constant function $g :P \to \Bbb{R}$ and define $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, by $f(x) = g([x])$ where $[x]$ denotes the $\sim$-equivalence class of $x$. Then with $D = \Bbb{Q}$ any interval $I$ of positive length meets $D$ and $|f(x + t) - f(x)| = 0$ for any $t \in D$.

Comment: That even works with all the quantors swapped into a harder order

Comment: Quite so! In fact, I nearly begin by querying whether the order of the quantifiers was as intended: it makes life very easy if you can choose $r$. Kudos to you for answering the question exactly as stated rather than the implicitly harder statement hiding under the hood.